# Sharepoint 2013 and Sql Express reached Full

Tags: sharepoint, sql-server-express, shrink

I've a standalone farm configured with SharePoint 2013 Foundation and sql server 2012 express.

I reached out on my content db limit(10gb) and I can no longer perform CRUD on the elements of sharepoint .

I would simply remove two large document library , to lower the space occupied, but the delete always goes wrong with the code "x80131904".

I also tried running the shrink on the db but without result, I've got always the same error when I try to delete those lists.

Have you any idea on how I can remove part of my content?
thank you

Comment: I just quick googled the error code. Seems to be a Login/security/authentification error. 
http://p2p.wrox.com/asp-net-2-0-basics/53774-sqlexception-0x80131904-cannot-open-user-defau.html

Comment: i'm logged as system account and i'm db.owner